# Saving to MongoDB when Socket.io event is emitted

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, mongodb, socket.io

I'm utilizing a MEAN stack and Socket.io to pull images from the real-time Instagram API. Everything is working great, but I now want to begin saving image data to a MongoDB database so I have a "history" of images from locations (rather than simply the most recent photos).
Below is the relevant (working) code I have so far:

Node server-side code to handle new photo updates from Instagram API and emit event to Angular controller:

```
// for each new post Instagram sends the data
app.post('/callback', function(req, res) {
    var data = req.body;

    // grab the object_id (as geo_id) of the subscription and send as an argument to the client side
    data.forEach(function(data) {
        var geo_id = data.object_id;
        sendUpdate(geo_id);
    });
    res.end();
});

// send the url with the geo_id to the client side
// to do the ajax call
function sendUpdate(geo_id) {
    io.sockets.emit('newImage', { geo_id: geo_id });
}
```

Angular controller code when 'newImage' event is received:

```
socket.on('newImage', function(geo_id) {
    // pass geo_id into Instagram API call
    Instagram.get(geo_id).success(function(response) {
        instagramSuccess(response.geo_id, response);
    });

    // Instagram API callback
    var instagramSuccess = function(scope,res) {
        if (res.meta.code !== 200) {
            scope.error = res.meta.error_type + ' | ' + res.meta.error_message;
            return;
        }
        if (res.data.length > 0) {
            $scope.items = res.data;
        } else {
            scope.error = "This location has returned no results";
        }
    };
});
```

Angular factory to handle calls to Instagram API:

```
angular.module('InstaFactory', []).factory('Instagram', function($http) {
    var base = "https://api.instagram.com/v1";
    var client_id = 'MY-CLIENT-ID';

    return {
        'get': function(geo_id) {
            var request = '/geographies/' + geo_id.geo_id + '/media/recent?client_id=' + client_id;
            var url = base + request;
            var config = {
                'params': {
                    'callback': 'JSON_CALLBACK'
                }
            };
            return $http.jsonp(url, config);
        }
    };
```

});

I also have the following Angular Controller which currently GETS details of each location from my Stadia mongoDB model. This model also contains an (empty for now) 'photos' array that I want to PUSH photo details (url, username, user profile url, etc.) onto each time I receive them from Instagram:

```
angular.module('StadiaFactory', []).factory('Stadia', function($http) {
    var base = "http://localhost:6060/api/stadia/";

    return {
        'get': function(id) {
            var request = id;
            var url = base + request;
            var config = {
                'params': {
                    'callback': 'JSON_CALLBACK'
                }
            };
            return $http.jsonp(url, config);
        }
    };

});
```

This is where I get confused. Where do I fire off the PUT request to my Stadia API and does this Node route for my Stadia API look reasonable? Note: I omitted my GET route which works perfectly. PUT is just throwing me for a loop:

```
// add photos to stadium photos array
app.put('/api/stadia/:stadium_id', function(req, res) {

    // use mongoose to get and update stadium
    Stadium.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.stadium_id,
        {$push: {"photos": {img: ?, link: ?, username: ?, profile_picture: ?}}},
        {safe: true, upsert: true},
        function(err, stadium) {

        // if there is an error retrieving, send the error. nothing after res.send(err) will execute
        if (err)
            res.send(err)

        res.jsonp(stadium); // return stadium in JSON format
    });
});
```

Comment: Just update socket.on('newImage', function(geo_id) {}) with the mongo db code right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are a few problems with your current structure.

When your `callback` route is called, with a possibility of `N` objects in it, you're triggering your *socket event* and retrieving all the last photos of your geography each time. So let's say you will have 3 new objects, you will call 3 times the same thing to get the same data, which is a bit loss when you have the power of the `sockets`.

You can also have problems if you try to get the object data from the client-side and `PUT`ing it to your server, since all your clients may receive the socket and you could end-up with duplicates, not to mention that this is a lot of traffic for not much, and this will burn your quota API limit, which is **also not safe on the client-side** since everyone can see your key.

---

To me, a good way to get something working (even if I don't really know what your `:stadium_id` param stands for) is to get the info you want directly on the server side in your `callback` using the **[request](https://github.com/request/request)** module.

You should only get the pictures, because you can retrieve a lot of things like `users`, `tags` or `videos` that you may don't want to get. So you will have to listen for the `image` objects, and nothing else.

You could have something like this:

```
var request = require('request');
var CLIENT_ID = 'yourId';

function newImage(data) {
  io.sockets.emit('newImage', data);
}

app.post('/callback', function (req, res) {

  //loop in all the new objects
  req.body.forEach(function (data) {

    if (data.type !== 'image') { return ; }

    //BTW I think you should try with the id property instead of object_id
    request('https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/' + data.object_id + '?access_token=' + CLIENT_ID,
      function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) { return ; }
        //Here we have one JSON object with all the info about the image
        var image = JSON.parse(body);

        //Save the new object to your DB. (replace the STADIUM_ID)
        Stadium.findByIdAndUpdate(STADIUM_ID, { $push: {'photos':
          { img: image.images.standard_resolution.url,
            link: image.link,
            username: image.user.username,
            profile_picture: image.user.profile_picture
          }}},
          { safe: true, upsert: true });

        //Send a socket to your client with the new image
        newImage({
          id: image.id,
          img: image.images.standard_resolution.url,
          link: image.link,
          username: image.user.username,
          profile: image.user.profile_picture
        });
      }
  });

  res.end();

});
```

And then in your client, you will only have to push the new images received in the `newImage` socket event in the `$scope.items`.